# About meditation for memory and concentration

Tags: yoga, meditation

Someone had suggested to me (5-6 years ago) to "gaze on a black dot marked on an clean wall" to increase concentration.
I used to do it whenever i felt lack of concentration.

A few days ago, when i was reading an answer here on stackexchange i came to know that it's actually a type of meditation....called Trātaka.
It's useful for increasing mind awareness, concentration and focus (atleast in my case it worked)

I'm wondering if there's any certain type practice or yoga which helps in increasing someone's Memory ( to be precise.....remembering and recalling ) ?

Thanks for any useful information in advance :)

Comment: While this question doesn't deal with exact standards of site, actually meditation is neither concentration nor anything. Meditation is a stage of inner silence of mind where you experience complete peace. Rest are just practice of one pointed mind. Mindfulness awareness all fancy words.

Comment: I'll edit my my question a little bit if it's confusing.

Comment: And all i said was Trātaka is type of meditation whose continuous use will make the mind focused. I did not say 'Meditation is concentration' at all.

Comment: When meditation happens contionously, mind will always be at peace which means you can focus easily at what you want to do.... so focus, concentration in your actions will automatically be there when there is inner peace!

Comment: Diet is a big factor, you should investigate that as well.

Answer (score 3):

[Secret of unfailing Memory revealed by Swami Vivekananda](http://celibacylife.blogspot.com/2013/02/quotes-by-swami-vivekananda-chief.html)

> Swami Vivekananda attributed his phenomenal mental powers to a
>   lifelong observance of brahmacharya. A few days ago, a new set of the
>   Encyclopedia Britannica had been bought for the Math. Seeing the new
>   shining volumes, the disciple said to Swamiji, “It is almost
>   impossible to read all these books in a single lifetime.” He was
>   unaware that Swamiji had already finished ten volumes and had begun
>   the eleventh.Swamiji: What do you say? Ask me anything you like from
>   these ten volumes, and I will answer you all.The disciple asked in
>   wonder, “Have you read all these books?” Swamiji: Why should I ask you
>   to question me otherwise?Being examined, Swamiji not only reproduced
>   the sense, but at places the very language of the difficult topics
>   selected from each volume. The disciple, astonished, put aside the
>   books, saying, “This is not within human power!”**Swamiji: Do you see,
>   simply by the observance of strict Brahmacharya (continence) all
>   learning can be mastered in a very short time — one has an unfailing
>   memory of what one hears or knows but once**. It is owing to this
>   habit of not observing continence that everything is on the brink of
>   ruin in our country.
>
> His childhood friend: Whatever you may say, I cannot bring myself to
>   believe in these words. Who can come by that oratorical power of
>   expounding philosophy which you have? **Swamiji: You don’t know! That
>   power may come to all. That power comes to him who observes unbroken
>   Brahmacharya for a period of twelve years, with the sole object of
>   realising God I have practiced that kind of Brahmacharya myself, and
>   so a screen has been removed, as it were, from my brain. For that
>   reason, I need not any more think over or prepare myself for any
>   lectures on such a subtle subject as philosophy.** Suppose I have to
>   lecture tomorrow; all that I shall speak about will pass tonight
>   before my eyes like so many pictures; and the next day I put into
>   words during my lecture all those things that I saw. So you will
>   understand now that it is not any power which is exclusively my own.
>   Whoever will practice unbroken Brahmacharya for twelve years will
>   surely have it. If you do so, you too will get it. Our Shâstras do not
>   say that only such and such a person will get it and not others!
>
> The chaste brain has tremendous energy and gigantic will power.
>   Without chastity there can be no spiritual strength. Continence gives
>   wonderful control over mankind.The spiritual leaders of men have been
>   very continent and this is what gave them power.
>
> I heard him say on his wonderful power of retentive memory in this
>   manner. “If a person can be continent for twelve years, he can have
>   extraordinary memory. One must be celibate and keep his brahmacharya
>   absolutely even in his dream.“
>
> From Mrs. George Roorbach’s reminiscences of Swami Vivekananda at Camp
>   Taylor, California, in May 1900:“In my first speech in this country,
>   in Chicago, **I addressed that audience as ‘Sisters and Brothers of
>   America’, and you know that they all rose to their feet. You may
>   wonder what made them do this, you may wonder if I had some strange
>   power. Let me tell you that I did have a power and this is it — never
>   once in my life did I allow myself to have even one sexual thought. I
>   trained my mind, my thinking, and the powers that man usually uses
>   along that line I put into a higher channel, and it developed a force
>   so strong that nothing could resist it.”**

Comment: Thank you brother for your response. Is continence here only implies "feelings and emotions about sex" ? I remember reading once, Swami Vivekananda's guru Ramakrishna Paramhansa taking about 'a memory nerve' which a person develop by not indulging in sexual activities for 12 years. Is Swami Vivekananda talking about the same "memory nerve" here ?

Comment: And if practising brahmacharya leads to unfailing memory........Is the converse i.e indulging in sexual activities reduces brain power and memory ?