# Mantra for fast comprehension

Tags: mantras

Eka-santha grahi refers to a person who comprehends any thing by one time.

In general, comprehension depends on Shradda (faith) and Chitta.

Krishna explains the role of faith in [geetha](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/4/verse/39)

> श्रद्धावान् लभते ज्ञानं
>
> Those whose faith is deep attain (divine) knowledge.

And many sastras explain about role of ekagra-chitta.

Keep ekagra-chitta aside. Lot of people has less shradda and hence has less comprehension rate. If a person first attains shradda then ekagra-chitta can also be invoked by practice.

Is there any manta that results in increasing shradda in a person to make him/her Eka-santha grahi.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar ha, but I think it may be suitable to start another question for shradda. Hoping some  mantra may be there.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35082/16530